# How to add external scss file in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, sass

I purchased a theme from Colorlib, the Bootstrap Sidebar V02, containing SCSS files. What are the relevant methods to add this external SCSS file to a Laravel project?

mix.sass('resources/sass/styles.scss', 'public/css').watch('resources/sass');
I just run this code in Terminal and create a sass file in the public folder, but it does not work

Comment: open resources/sass/app.scss and import your scss path file, like this: @import 'path/to/scss';

Answer (score 0):

You can add a normal external css file. Add the file name in the second parameter like:

```
mix.sass('resources/sass/styles.scss', 'public/css/styles.css').watch('resources/sass');
```

Then write this command in the terminal:

```
npm run prod/npm run watch
```